# How to call a \newcommand in a FOR loop - automated document preparation

Tags: macros, loops

I'm working on a technical report which I need to simplify in order to get rid of ridiculous manual copy-paste work.

My ideas:

- My simulation results can be presented in the
  same way (same variables, pictures and tables)

What I already tried:

- I'm familiar with the \newcommand limitation regarding numbers in name - Roman numbers are OK for me

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

   % Variables definition

        % Simulation results example 
        \newcommand{\NameCI}{Acceleration}
        \newcommand{\ResultCI}{OK}
        \newcommand{\CommentCI}{My description 1}

        % Simulation results example 
        \newcommand{\NameCII}{Deceleration}
        \newcommand{\ResultCII}{NOT OK}
        \newcommand{\commentCII}{My description 2}

    % FOR loop - results presentation 
    % (this should prepare a dedicated page for each simulation 
    % and use my already defined variables)
        
    \foreach \x in {I, II}
    {
        Simulation name: \NameC\x  
        Simulation result: \ResultC\x
        % code for pictures and tables which uses more variables like these above
    }
        
\end{document}
```

The problem:

- How to iterate through my variables in order to prepare the page template once and fill all defined variables (some similar application would be the serial correspondence from MS Office)

Comment: As always on the site please provide a full but minimal example others can just copy and try as is.  Then for example they don't have to look up where `\foreach` comes from.

Comment: `\CaseName\x` are two different macros, `\CaseNameI` is one, LaTeX does not work that way.. Have a look at the `etoolbox` package and its `\csuse` macro, using  `\csuse{CaseName\x}`  builds a macro name from the argument and then runs it.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. The code is updated. I will try with etoolbox package but it's a little bit overwhelming for me. In anyway I start with its documentation - thanks!

Comment: It is very easy `\csuse{Foo\bar}` expands `\bar` to what ever value it has, lets say `Bat`. Thus now it has `FooBat` and then the command will expand/execute the macro `\FooBat` (if it exists). This is precisely what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

See **ADDENDUM** for a more expansive implementation.

I think `listofitems` is useful for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\newcommands[2]{%
  \readlist*\cmdtxt{#2}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\cmdtxt[]{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname#1\romannumeral\zcnt\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter{\z}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\newcommands{CaseName}{Acceleration, Deceleration, Right turn, Left Turn}
\CaseNameiii{} and \CaseNameiv, followed by \CaseNameii{} and
\CaseNamei.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist to have uppercase roman numerals, then this variation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcounter{cmdctr}
\newcommand\newcommands[2]{%
  \readlist*\cmdtxt{#2}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\cmdtxt[]{%
    \setcounter{cmdctr}{\zcnt}%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname#1\Roman{cmdctr}\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter{\z}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\newcommands{CaseName}{Acceleration, Deceleration, Right turn, Left Turn}
\CaseNameIII{} and \CaseNameIV, followed by \CaseNameII{} and
\CaseNameI.
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM**

Perhaps this is more in line with what the OP wants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\newcommands[2]{%
  \readlist*\cmdtxt{#2}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\cmdtxt[]{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname#1\romannumeral\zcnt\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter{\z}%
  }%
}
\newcommand\usecmd[1]{\csname#1\romannumeral\z\endcsname}
\newcommand\fillstencil[2]{%
  \readlist*\numcnt{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\numcnt[]{%
    #2
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\newcommands{CaseName}{Acceleration, Deceleration, Right turn, Left Turn}
\newcommands{Result}{OK, OK, Not OK, Maybe OK}

\fillstencil{1,2,4}{%
\subsection{Subject: \usecmd{CaseName}!}

The result was \usecmd{Result}

The end
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this idea. There is only one concern from my site - I prefer to specify my inputs/variables one by one rather than in form of a list. Such list could be a very dangerous if I make a mistake in results order. I've made my post more precise to indicate my problem more clearly.

Comment: @Jakubat One does not have to use my `\newcommands` macro.  You can still define them individually, in lieu of it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in Dr. Nicola Talbot's [datatool](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool)-package for maintaining databases and for iterating on elements of records of databases.

Examples on how to approach the matter using the [datatool](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool)-package are at the end of this answer.

Be that as it may.

`\csname..\endcsname` might be your friend:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

   % Variables definition

        % Simulation results example 
        \newcommand{\NameCI}{Acceleration}
        \newcommand{\ResultCI}{OK}
        \newcommand{\CommentCI}{My description 1}

        % Simulation results example 
        \newcommand{\NameCII}{Deceleration}
        \newcommand{\ResultCII}{NOT OK}
        \newcommand{\CommentCII}{My description 2}

    % FOR loop - results presentation 
    % (this should prepare a dedicated paragraph for each simulation 
    %  and use the already defined variables)
        
    \foreach \x in {I, II}
    {%
        \par\noindent
        \textbf{Simulation name:} \csname NameC\x\endcsname\\
        \textbf{Simulation description:} \csname CommentC\x\endcsname\\
        \textbf{Simulation result:} \csname ResultC\x\endcsname\\
        \textbf{Control-sequence-names:} 
           \texttt{\expandafter\string\csname NameC\x\endcsname}/%
           \texttt{\expandafter\string\csname CommentC\x\endcsname}/%
           \texttt{\expandafter\string\csname ResultC\x\endcsname}%
        % code for pictures and tables which uses more variables like these above
        \bigskip
    }
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

I sometimes use a macro `\NameToCs` which processes an argument which is delimited by a left curly brace (`{`) and an argument which is nested in braces.

`\NameToCs` works as follows:

```
\NameToCs⟨stuff not in curly braces⟩{NameOfCs}
→
⟨stuff not in curly braces⟩\NameOfCs
```

The argument nested in braces is taken for the name of a `⟨control sequence token⟩` which is to be constructed via `\csname`..`\endcsname`. In the `⟨parameter text⟩` of a macro-definition you can use `#{`-notation for a macro whose last argument will be delimited by a `{` which will (unlike other argument-delimiters) be left in place/be re-insered:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\NameToCs{\long\def\NameToCs#1#{\romannumeral0\innerNameToCs{#1}}}%
\newcommand\innerNameToCs[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}}%
\makeatother
```

There are various uses for such a macro:

**1)** `\NameToCs{foo}` → `\foo`
**2)** `\NameToCs\string{foo}` → `\string\foo`
**3)** `\NameToCs\meaning{foo}` → `\meaning\foo`
**4)** `\NameToCs\global\long\def{foo}...` → `\global\long\foo...`
**5)** `\NameToCs\newcommand*{foo}...` → `\newcommand*\foo...`
**6)** `\NameToCs\NameToCs\global\let{foo}={bar}` → `\NameToCs\global\let\foo={bar}`  → `\global\let\foo=\bar`

Basically `\NameToCs` is just a wrapper for applying `\csname..\endcsname` and appending the resulting `⟨control sequence token⟩` to some token sequence for further processing, e.g., defining or just calling.

**You can use `\csname..\endcsame`/`\NameToCs` for creating a `⟨control sequence token⟩` whose name contains spaces and/or arabic digits.** `\csname..\endcsame`/`\NameToCs` whill expand expandable tokens (e.g. `\the⟨counter⟩`) while gathering the name of the `⟨control sequence token⟩` to create. The `⟨control sequence token⟩` created by `\csname..\endcsame`/`\NameToCs` can be used in whatsoever ways. E.g., for defining or for calling the control sequence in question.
If a `⟨control sequence token⟩` created by `\csname..\endcsame`/`\NameToCs` was undefined at the time of creating it, the underlying  `\csname..\endcsame` causes TeX to let its meaning be equal to the meaning of the `\relax`-primitive within the **current** scope/group but not within parent-scopes/superordinate scopes(even when the `\globaldefs`-parameter has a positive value).   (This will not disturb `\newcommand` as `\newcommand` treats control sequences that are equal to `\relax` in the same way in which it treats control sequences that are undefined.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\NameToCs{\long\def\NameToCs#1#{\romannumeral0\innerNameToCs{#1}}}%
\newcommand\innerNameToCs[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}}%

\newcommand\simulationlist{}
\newcommand\appendtosimulationlist{%
      \ifnum\value{simulation}>1 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
      {\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\expandafter,\number\value{simulation}}}}%
      {\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\number\value{simulation}}}}%
      {\g@addto@macro{\simulationlist}}%
}%
\makeatother

\newcounter{simulation}
\setcounter{simulation}{0}
\renewcommand\thesimulation{\arabic{simulation}}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

   % Variables definition

        % Simulation results example     
        \stepcounter{simulation}
        % Now the simulation-counter's value is 1.
        \appendtosimulationlist
        % Now "1" is appended to the definition of \simulationlist.
        \NameToCs\newcommand{Name\number\value{simulation}}{Acceleration}
        \NameToCs\newcommand{Result\number\value{simulation}}{OK}
        \NameToCs\newcommand{Description\number\value{simulation}}{My description 1}

        % Simulation results example 
        \stepcounter{simulation}
        % Now the simulation-counter's value is 2.
        \appendtosimulationlist
        % Now ",2" is appended to the definition of \simulationlist.
        \NameToCs\newcommand{Name\number\value{simulation}}{Deceleration}
        \NameToCs\newcommand{Result\number\value{simulation}}{NOT OK}
        \NameToCs\newcommand{Description\number\value{simulation}}{My description 2}

    % loop - results presentation 
    % (this should prepare a dedicated paragraph for each simulation 
    %  and use the already defined variables)


    \noindent A \verb|\foreach|-loop:\bigskip

    \foreach \x in \simulationlist
    {%
        \par\noindent
        \textbf{Simulation name:} \NameToCs{Name\x}\\
        \textbf{Simulation description:} \NameToCs{Description\x}\\
        \textbf{Simulation result:} \NameToCs{Result\x}\\
        \textbf{Control-sequence-names:} 
           \texttt{\NameToCs\string{Name\x}}/%
           \texttt{\NameToCs\string{Description\x}}/%
           \texttt{\NameToCs\string{Result\x}}%
        % code for pictures and tables which uses more variables like these above
        \bigskip
    }
    
    \noindent A \verb|\loop..\ifnum..\repeat|-loop:\bigskip
    
    \newcount\loopcount
    \loopcount=0
    \loop
    \ifnum\loopcount<2 %
       \advance\loopcount by 1
       \par\noindent
       \textbf{Simulation name:} \NameToCs{Name\the\loopcount}\\
       \textbf{Simulation description:} \NameToCs{Description\the\loopcount}\\
       \textbf{Simulation result:} \NameToCs{Result\the\loopcount}\\
       \textbf{Control-sequence-names:} 
          \texttt{\NameToCs\string{Name\the\loopcount}}/%
          \texttt{\NameToCs\string{Description\the\loopcount}}/%
          \texttt{\NameToCs\string{Result\the\loopcount}}%
       % code for pictures and tables which uses more variables like these above
       \bigskip
    \repeat
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an approach, using the [datatool-package](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool)'s commands both for maintaining a database and for iterating on that database:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\newcounter{AmountOfSimulations}
\DTLnewdb{simulations}

\begin{document}

% Simulation results example     
\DTLnewrow{simulations}%
\stepcounter{AmountOfSimulations}%
\DTLnewdbentry{simulations}{Name}{Acceleration}%
\DTLnewdbentry{simulations}{Result}{OK}%
\dtlexpandnewvalue
\DTLnewdbentry{simulations}{Description}{My description \number\value{AmountOfSimulations}}%
\dtlnoexpandnewvalue

% Simulation results example     
\DTLnewrow{simulations}%
\stepcounter{AmountOfSimulations}%
\DTLnewdbentry{simulations}{Name}{Deceleration}%
\DTLnewdbentry{simulations}{Result}{NOT OK}%
\dtlexpandnewvalue
\DTLnewdbentry{simulations}{Description}{My description \number\value{AmountOfSimulations}}%
\dtlnoexpandnewvalue

% FOR loop - results presentation 
% (this should prepare a dedicated paragraph for each simulation)

\DTLforeach{simulations}{\NameField=Name, \ResultField=Result, \DescriptionField=Description}{%
    \par\noindent
    \textbf{Simulation name:} \NameField\\
    \textbf{Simulation description:} \DescriptionField\\
    \textbf{Simulation result:} \ResultField
    % code for pictures and tables which uses more variables like these above
    \bigskip
}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an approach, using a .csv-file (comma separated values-file) for maintaining the database and [datatool-package](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool)'s commands both for loading that database and for iterating on that database:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{CSVDataBaseOfMyInterestingSimulations.csv}
Name,Result,Description
"Acceleration","OK","My Description 1"
"Deceleration","NOT OK","My Description 2"
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb{simulations}{CSVDataBaseOfMyInterestingSimulations.csv}

\begin{document}

% FOR loop - results presentation 
% (this should prepare a dedicated paragraph for each simulation)

\DTLforeach{simulations}{\NameField=Name, \ResultField=Result, \DescriptionField=Description}{%
    \par\noindent
    \textbf{Simulation name:} \NameField\\
    \textbf{Simulation description:} \DescriptionField\\
    \textbf{Simulation result:} \ResultField
    % code for pictures and tables which uses more variables like these above
    \bigskip
}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]